# Run all the junit tests that are in a given package in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

We have a bunch junit tests in our current project. Essentially we are looking for a way to run all the test in a given package. Currently in Netbeans I see you can run all the tests or a single test, but no way to run a a sub-set of tests.

Is this built into Netbeans? Or is there another way we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JUnit this is achieved through TestSuite. You can check for more information [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JUnit/article.html#juniteclipse_testsuite) (look at the code, not at the pictures).
At least in the Eclipse IDE there is a functionality that lets you add a new TestSuite, select which tests it is to include and then have the IDE generate it for you. 
I haven't seen such thing in Netbeans, but you should check for any additional JUnit plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up junit test groups like documented e.g. [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817135/grouping-junit-tests) and then run the test group via your ant or maven build.