# How do I make JUnit ignore specific test case at run time when run with Parameterized runner?

Tags: java, junit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditionally ignoring tests in JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4)

I have a suite of system tests that are run with `Parameterized` runner and that I would like to run against different environments. Some of the tests should only run in non-production environments, and when run in production I would like to see them as ignored, so I'm looking for a way to say:

```
@Test
public void dangerousTest() {
    if (isProduction(environment)) ignore(); // JUnit doesn't provide ignore()
    environment.launchMissilesAt(target);
    assertThat(target, is(destroyed()));
}
```

The issue is that JUnit doesn't provide `ignore()` method to ignore a test case at run time. Furthermore, `Assume.assumeTrue(isNotProduction(environment))` doesn't seem to work with `Parameterized` runner -- it simply marks the tests as passed, not ignored. Any ideas how something equivalent can be achieved with the constraints that:

- the suite needs to use `Parameterized` runner
- the tests need to appear as ignored if the suite is run in production?

Comment: Take a look here maybe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817135/grouping-junit-tests

Answer (score 5):

You could always do

```
if (isProduction(environment)) return;
```

The test would be marked as passed, but at least the missiles wouldn't be launched.

Or you could use [Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html), which I've never used, but is documented this way:

> A set of methods useful for stating
>   assumptions about the conditions in
>   which a test is meaningful. A failed
>   assumption does not mean the code is
>   broken, but that the test provides no
>   useful information. The default JUnit
>   runner treats tests with failing
>   assumptions as ignored. Custom runners
>   may behave differently. For example:

Your code would thus look like this:

```
@Test
public void dangerousTest() {
    assumeTrue(!isProduction(environment));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, but my requirement is for it to be marked as ignored by JUnit.

Comment: Thanks; I tried that but it seems the runner I use doesn't honour `AssumptionViolatedException`s. Question updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

- JUnit's assumptions do not work as you would expect: [if they fail, they still mark the test as passed](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/ReleaseNotes4.4.html):

> With this release, a failed assumption
>   will lead to the test being marked as
>   passing, regardless of what the code
>   below the assumption may assert. In
>   the future, this may change, and a
>   failed assumption may lead to the test
>   being ignored: however, third-party
>   runners do not currently allow this
>   option.

I find this very counter intuitive as well, and even more frightening is the fact that this behavior might change in the future. I wish they had just held onto that feature until it worked as expected.

- If using [TestNG](http://testng.org) is an option, you could use groups for this. Put your test method in the "production" group:

  ```
  @Test(groups = "production")
  public void dangerousTest() { ... }
  ```

and when you are running your test, exclude the group "production".