# maven - fail build when unit test takes too long

Tags: java, testing, maven, junit, build-process

I have in my project a lot of unit tests, written in JUnit and TestNG. The building process is based on maven with surefire plugin.

Is there any way/plugin for maven to fail the build when at least one unit test takes too many seconds? I know that there are some plugins to fail build in TeamCity, Jenkins but this is "too far".

In my project I want to have only fast tests to have unit testing process effective. I can improve my old tests but I need to protect for the future commitments

Comment: Failing unit tests because they run too long is part of the framework you're using to run these test cases. Are you using JUnit or TestNG?

Comment: I don't want to fail separate unit test, I want to fail all build if at least one unit test takes too long. I'm using JUnit and TestNG

Comment: If you fail one unit test it will fail the build also unless you ask the plugin not too.

Comment: right, but I can't just add the timeout annotation to all my unit tests. This is too painful and don't resolve problem in the future

Comment: You can also just set the timout at the suite level in your testng xml file. <suite name="Integration Suite" time-out="30000">

Answer (score 15):

If all your tests extend some base class, I think you can stick `@Rule` in there which will apply to all the `@Test` in the child class.

e.g.

```
import org.junit.rules.Timeout;
public abstract class BaseTestConfiguration {
    @Rule public Timeout testTimeout = new Timeout(60000); // 60k ms = 1 minute
}

public class ThingTests extends BaseTestConfiguration {
    @Test
    public void testThis() {
        /*will fail if not done in 1 minute*/
    }
    @Test
    public void testThat() {
        /*will fail if not done in 1 minute*/
    }
}
```

We found this to be easiest rather than messing with AspectJ or secret configuration directives. Devs are more likely to figure out the Java parts than all the secret XML this and that.
You can put `@Before` `@After` and any number of other junit directives in the base class too.

Comment: But in his scenario we have many test cases. We need to extend all the tests to BaseTestConfiguration.

Comment: While this is an extra step to creating tests, this is by far the easiest implementation I've yet seen.

Comment: Yeah I realized that was definitely a critical caveat, that you might have to put in an initial cost to get all your tests to extend something when they didn't already. Since the OP has more information than we do, figured it worth mentioning anyways.

Answer (score 7):

In maven surefire, you can use [forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds), along with `forkMode=once`.

This will kill the forked jvm if it takes too long. If you want to do this per test, you can forkMode=pertest or forkMode=always (which does it for each class).

Comment: in real world - forking is not effective

Answer (score 4):

Why don't add a timeout on a per test basis. I assume you're programming in Java, so in JUnit you can do something like this:

```
 @Test(timeout=100) public void testQuickly()
```

If the test doesn't end after 100 milliseconds, it will fail.

Comment: What if you have gazillions tests and want to have one constant value in seconds to control this requirements? It can't be set per test.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried specifying the timeout for the test through @Test(timeout=xx)? Find the official api documentation here: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html

EDIT---

You can also consider using the timeout property for the TestNg suite, you will have to move all your tests to TestNg though, but this will allow you to specify timeouts for groups.

This is the official api documentation: http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/xml/XmlSuite.html#setTimeOut(java.lang.String)

Comment: I can't do this because I have quite big project and huge amount of tests.

Comment: Check my edit, I think with testNg you will be able to specify a timeout for an entire suite

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same requirement, and since I was using TestNG, I used the ["group feature"](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups).

If you're stuck with JUnit, try using the tests suite (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817135/grouping-junit-tests)

Comment: You can also just set the timout at the suite level in your testng xml file. <suite name="Integration Suite" time-out="30000">

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the junit Ant task with the timeout parameter.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

EDIT:
Another thing you can do is to use aspectj with someting like that:

```
public aspect TestTimeoutChecker {
    long TIMEOUT = 60000;

    pointcut invokeEvent() :
        execution(@Test * *(..));

    Object around() : invokeEvent() {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object object = proceed();
        long took = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        if (took > TIMEOUT) {
            throw new RuntimeException("timeout! it took:" + took);
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: I considered it, but requires fork mode - which is unacceptable in large projects