# Java Selenium Junit Maven: Way to parametrize tests?

Tags: java, maven, junit, selenium-webdriver

I have a test suite that is being run on a bunch of sites we have created. The majority of the sites work the same way so instead of having lots of duplicate code I can run all the tests on all sites.

I now have a a couple of tests that I only want run on a few of the sites, is there a way to only run these tests if the url is for site A,B or C?

For each site I read in a properties file which has the url and other information needed in the test, would it be possible to have a property ignoreTests= followed by the tests to ignore and then when I read the properties file in the @Before section of the tests I can set each @Test read in to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Everything what you're asking here can be obtained with TestNG instead of Junit.

Parametrization of test cases is described in [this](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/) good tutorial.
As for selective run of test cases I think that grouping would be usefull, [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_group_test.htm) is tutorial.

Generally TestNG hase greate [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) which I recomend you to read.

If you can't swith to TestNG take a look on [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm) tutorial for test parametrization in Junit.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817135/grouping-junit-tests) is SO about Junit test grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Junit uses [Assume](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.8/index.html?org/junit/Assume.html) for dynamically ignoring tests.

Use the @Before method to write the URL to a field. Than you can use Assume for ingoring tests based on the URL. The following tests are ignored if the URL is not "firstValidUrl" or "secondValidUrl".

```
org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(url.equals("firstValidUrl") || url.equals("secondValidUrl"));
```

You can use [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org) for a much nicer statement:

```
org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(url, org.hamcrest.Matchers.isIn("firstValidUrl", "secondValidUrl"));
```

Using static imports and Hamcrest:

```
assumeTrue(url, isIn("firstValidUrl", "secondValidUrl");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can Parameterize with JUnit but you need to make sure you are using JUNit 4.11 or newer.  JUNit didn't have parameterization before that.   JUnit has Data Providers and Annotations that are almost exactly like TestNG, using a 2-D object array (List).