# Maven + jUnit4: Include tests based on test name

Tags: maven, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

Im trying to run some selected tests from my Test class based on the test case name.

Below is an outline of my test class

----GlobalTests.java----

```
@Test
public void myTest_India(){ --- }

@Test
public void myTest_Germany() { --- }
```

----GlobalIntegrationTests.java----

```
@Test
public void myIntegrationTest_India(){ --- }

@Test
public void myIntegrationTest_Germany() { --- }
```

How do I instruct my maven to run only 'India' tests?

I've tried  in maven surefire plugin as below

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>%regex[*Test_India*]</include>
                    </includes>                    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But seems like this configuration is for selecting test class names and NOT test names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250009/is-there-a-way-using-surefire-to-exclude-tests-at-a-test-method-level-not-a-cl

Comment: @MAnouti Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using maven's 'test' property
Tests to be run can be defined as testClass#testName
Below approach worked

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <test>*#*India</test>
    </properties>
</project>
```

and run as

```
mvn test
```

or directly from the command line as `mvn -Dtest="*#*India"`