# How to Run particular @Test methods from a class using TestSuite.class file?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have a class with methods like below...

```
class one{

    @Test
    method1{}

    @Test
    method2{}

    @Test
    method3{}

}
```

I m using below class to run above Tests using JUnit.

```
class runsuites{

    @RunWith(Suite.class)

    @SuiteClasses({

        one.class

    }

}
```

And this runs all the `@Test` methods.

But, i want to run only methods `method1` and `method3`.

How can I achieve this??

Comment: Side note: just because it is possible to @Ignore certain tests; be careful about really doing that. If some test is "flaky" for example (fails occasionally); then dont ignore it - find the root cause, and fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [Grouping JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817135/grouping-junit-tests)

You can use `@Category` to group tests. First create a category interface.

```
public interface MyCategory {}
```

Then add the category to the tests it should be in.

```
class One {

  @Test
  @Category(MyCategory.class)
  public void method1(){}

  @Test 
  public void method2(){}

  @Test
  @Category(MyCategory.class)
  public void method3(){}

}
```

And then create a suite for the category:

```
 @RunWith(Categories.class)
 @IncludeCategory(MyCategory.class)
 @SuiteClasses( { One.class })
 public class RunSuites {}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it with Categories.

Comment: Cool, you should accept one of the answers so that your question doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate method2 with `@Ignore` annotation. I think a better solution would require some custom library or setting up tests categories (which I recommend):

[read about tests categories here](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html)

Comment: Thanks, I got it with Categories.