# How can I run parallel tests with multiple group?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, testing, testng

I want to run 10 groups after each other, and every single group should contain 10 tests and each test running parallel.
I tried with a factory class, but if I placed It multiple times in the suite XML every single test started, so in this case 100 tests stated in parallel
How can I do It in testNG?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817135/grouping-junit-tests)

Comment: @MebinJoe OP asked for `TestNG` while the dupe target is using `JUnit`, I'm not a Java pro but it seems like a non-dupe for me