# Migration: JUnit 3 to JUnit 4: TestSuite

Tags: regex, junit, junit4, junit3

I was recently working with JUnit 3, but I decided to migrate to JUnit 4. Now Im facing the following problem:

I was using a TestSuite with JUnit 3, where I ran all java-Testclasses whose names matched a pattern like "*TestMe.java".

I've got a hundred tests which were named like this.

Now, with JUnit 4 I have to name them explicitly to call them in a TestSuite.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(
{
    FirstTestMe.class,
    SecondTestMe.class,
    ThirdTestMe.class,

})
public class TestMe
{
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    private TestMe()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

This is really uncomfortable and I possibly might forget to list some tests. Also, when I create a new one, I must add it there.

Is there any solution how to call those Test-Classes with a Regex or something else?

Also, one additional question: each method which is not a test, but maybe used in a test-class must be annotated with @Ignore?
I run those test-classes without any error, so I guess it is not necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the post [migrate-tests-from-junit-3-to-junit-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264680/best-way-to-automagically-migrate-tests-from-junit-3-to-junit-4) which discusses exactly what you want.

See if [Dynamically create a Test Suite in JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257080/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-test-suite-in-junit-4) or [Run all tests in Junit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255046/run-all-tests-in-junit-4) helps.

Comment: I just looked at it, but I didnt find the specific answer to this question. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add the @Test annotation above your test method.

```
public class TestMe
{
    @Before
    public void setUp() {

    }

    @Test
    public void myFirstTest() {
    }

}
```

Comment: This is just how to write a simple Test-Class. Im looking for a way how to call multiple TestClasses in one Suite. I want to be able to run a specific selection of TestClasses. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, if you want to use a Test Suite in JUnit 4, then there isn't any option but to list all of the classes explicitly. If, however, you want to run all classes in a package, or in a project, you can just right click on the package/project in Eclipse and select `Run as JUnit test`. If you're using ant or maven surefire, you can specify the tests to run with a *Test.java or similar.

You don't have to annotate those methods which are not test methods with `@Ignore`.
The (major) difference between JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 is the use of annotations. So it JUnit3, you extend `TestCase` and name all of your methods testXXX. In JUnit 4, you don't have to extend TestCase, but you do have to annotate all of your test methods with `@Test`. So therefore, any methods not marked with `@Test` don't get run as test. Of course, there are other annotations such as `@Before` and `@After`, which replace `setUp()` and `tearDown()`.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to run a selection of TestClasses expect for specifying a profile in maven? I know how to run all tests, but I want to run just a selection. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source library [ClasspathSuite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp).  It allows you to use regular expressions to specify what class/package names should be or should not be included in your test suite.

Here's an example of use which includes everything in two packages but not in a third package.  It also excludes another specific class.

```
@ClassnameFilters( { "com.javaranch.*test.*", "net.jforum.*test.*", "!com.javaranch.test.web.*", "!.*All_JForum_Functional_Tests" })
```