# How to add test cases to a suite using jUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have 2 test classes, both extend `TestCase`. Each class contains a bunch of individual tests which run against my program.

How can I execute both classes (and all tests they have) as part of the same suite?

I am using jUnit 4.8.

Comment: you are extending TestCase in JUnit 4? Why are you not using annotations instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In jUnit4 you have something like this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    SomeTest.class,
    SomeOtherTest.class,
    ...
    })
public class AllTests {}
```

If you want the Eclipse GUI suite builder (New > JUnit Test suite), you have to add

```
public static junit.framework.Test suite() {
   return new JUnit4TestAdapter(SomeTest.class);
}
```

to each of your test classes s.t. the GUI test suite builder recognizes your test.

Answer (score 0):

Create TestClass and override suite() method and run newly created TestClass.

```
 public static Test suite()
    {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("Test ExpenseTest");
        suite.add(TestCase1.class);
        suite.add(TestCase2.class);
        return suite;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this JavaDoc will help http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/runners/Suite.html. I have never used it JavaDoc have enough information

Comment: My test set is invoked as part of @Suite.SuiteClasses({MyTests.class}). Where should I add your code to produce a subsuit? Who consumes the suite produced?

Comment: @VinayLodha, sorry, but cannot understand what class did you extend. And the link is not found.

Answer (score 0):

`JUnit 3` supported `TestSuite` and `public static Test suite()`. `JUnit 4` doesn't support it (it creates added test classes, but doesn't launch test methods).

But you can launch a subsuite of tests inside a suite.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Suite

@RunWith(Suite::class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(
    Test1::class,
    TestSuite1::class
)
class StartTest
```

Then inside `StartTest` you can add test classes and test suites.

```
@RunWith(Suite::class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(
    Test2::class,
    Test3::class,
    TestSuite2::class
)
class TestSuite1

@RunWith(Suite::class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(
    Test4::class,
    Test5::class
)
class TestSuite2
```

This way you can join test classes into groups (to have a list of 10 items instead of 100).