# How to get rid of java.lang.Exception: ... contains itself as a SuiteClass

Tags: java, junit4, classpathsuite

I'm using the [classpath suite library](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp) to automtically run all tests in a project, which works fine.

```
@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@SuiteTypes({RUN_WITH_CLASSES, TEST_CLASSES, JUNIT38_TEST_CLASSES})
@ClassnameFilters({"com.foo.bar.*"})
public class AllTests {
}
```

However, everytime I run `AllTests` I get this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: class 'com.foo.bar.AllTests' (possibly indirectly) contains itself as a SuiteClass
```

Any ideas how to get rid of this?

And yes, I've read [JUnit: (possibly indirectly) contains itself as a SuiteClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834908/junit-possibly-indirectly-contains-itself-as-a-suiteclass) but did not find an answer, since I'm not inheriting from `AllTests` in anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that none of the classes are extending something that is inheriting the test suite ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move your `AllTests` class to package `com.foo`.

You have selected `SuiteTypes=RUN_WITH_CLASSES` (and set target package to `com.foo.bar`), so your `AllTests` runs `AllTests` over and over.

Comment: You are right that classpathsuite does find the `AllTests` which forms a circular dependency. Since I didn't like the solution of moving `AllTests` up the package hierachy, I excluded it by adding `"!com.foo.bar.AllTests"` to `@ClassnameFilters`.