# Run all test from a hierarchy

Tags: java, junit

Using Java and jUnit, let's say I have a test class A, test class B extends A, test class C extends B, and D extends A and many others test classes that aren't part of A hierarchy.

How can I run all the test contained in subclasses of A without run others?

Comment: Why would you *not* want to run *all* unit tests?

Comment: Because in the real problem I have a lot of tests, and it takes time.

Comment: you could create a test suite. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457276/junit4-test-suites